# characterization of Principal ideal rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm thinking about these statements and I would like to know if I am right.

1. A principal ideal ring $R$, by definition, is a ring whose ideals are principals, since $R$ is itself an ideal, $R=(x)$, for some $x\in R$.
2. If $R=(y)$ for some $y$, every ideal of $R$ is principal.
3. Using (1) and (2), the principal ideal rings are in this form $(x)$, for some element $x$ and vice and versa, every (x) is a principal ideal ring.

Am I wrong? I need some help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Every unital ring satisfies $R = (y)$ for some $y$.

Comment: @Ink $R$ is not necessarily unital.

Comment: And your point is?

Comment: @Ink I would like to know if what I said above is true, maybe I mistaken in some part.

Comment: There's an answer below that tells you why it's false.

Answer (score 4):

No argument for (2) has been supplied, and the assertion is not correct.

Consider for example the ring of all polynomials $P(x,y)$ with real coefficients. Certainly the whole ring is a principal ideal, since it is generated by the polynomial $1$. But the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$ is non-principal.

Comment: why the ideal generated by x and y is not principal?

Comment: This is the ideal of all polynomials that vanish at $(0,0)$. Can you think of a generator? It would have to be a polynomial that is $0$ at $(0,0)$. Since $x$ is in the ideal, it would have to look like $kx$.  But $y$ is not $kx$ times a polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Property (2) is completely wrong because any commutative unital ring $R = (1)$ and so this would imply that any commutative unital $R$ is a principal ideal ring! This is certainly not true for example by considering $R = \Bbb{Z}[x]$ and $I = (2,x)$: If $I$ is principal then since $R$ is Noetherian the Krull Hauptidealsatz implies that $I$ has height one which is a contradiction, for

$$0 \subsetneqq (x) \subsetneqq (2,x).$$